# Pass data URL from children after click to sibling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, fetch-api

I have applications for movies. I am fetching data from API tmdb. By default, popular videos are shown to me, but I have a list that changes my URL to other lists.

And now the problem begins. I can't pass URL data after `onClick` to a sibling from the Nav component to the ListApp component, because I have there one function to close navigation.

And also, I do not know how to use them in parent to replacing used URL popular.

**Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/9z6yll4r6r**

**Child component Nav.js (here I have list in Nav.js with new url)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class Navigation extends Component{
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {
            active: false
        };
        this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this);
    };
    
    // toggle Class after click menu and li elements or X
    toggleClass(){
        const currentState = this.state.active;
        this.setState({ active: !currentState });
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <nav className="navigation">   
                <NavLink to="/" className="navigation__link navigation__link--back"><span className="fa fa-angle-left navigation__icon"></span></NavLink>
                <button id="navBtnOpen" className="navigation__link navigation__link--list" onClick={this.toggleClass}>
                    <span className="fa fa-bars navigation__icon"></span>
                    <span className="navigation__title">MOVIE LISTS</span>
                </button>
                <div id="navList" className={"navigation__list " + (this.state.active ? 'navShow': null)}>
                    <button id="navBtnClose" className={"navigation__list-btn " + (this.state.active ? 'showXBtn': null)}><span className="fa fa-times" onClick={this.toggleClass}></span></button>

                    <div className="navigation__list-cont">
                        **<a href="#" className="navigation__list-item" id="popular" url={"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=642874b006093ef1d8becb7a5a90179c&page=1"} onClick={ (this.toggleClass)(this.url)}>Most popular</a>

                        <a href="#" className="navigation__list-item" id="nowPlaying" url={"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=642874b006093ef1d8becb7a5a90179c&page=1"} onClick={this.toggleClass}>Now playing</a>

                        <a href="#" className="navigation__list-item" id="topRated" url={"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=642874b006093ef1d8becb7a5a90179c&page=1"} onClick={this.toggleClass}>Top rated</a>

                        <a href="#" className="navigation__list-item" id="upcoming" url={"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?api_key=642874b006093ef1d8becb7a5a90179c&page=1"} onClick={this.toggleClass}>Upcoming</a>**
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        )
    }
}
export default Navigation;
```

**Parent with class ListApp.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from "./Card";

class ListApp extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
        // this.fetchApi = this.fetchApi.bind(this);
    }
    fetchApi(){
        const urlApi = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=642874b006093ef1d8becb7a5a90179c&page=1";
         
        return urlApi;
            
    }
    
    componentDidMount = () => {
        fetch(this.fetchApi())
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(resp => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                items: resp.results
            })
            console.log(this.state.items)
                 
    })  
};
    render() {
        var {isLoaded, items} = this.state;
        
        return (
            <div className="movie-section" id="movie-section">
                {items.map( (item) => ( <Card key={item.id} item={item} /> ) )};
            </div>
            
        );
    }
}

export default ListApp;
```

**---UPDATE 1---**

I do somethiing from that site https://codeburst.io/no-redux-strategy-for-siblings-communication-3db543538959 ,but now I have another problem.

I am passing data to sibling and I want to update my downloadable URL. So I used componentDidUpdate, but the callback () function still causes loops for fetch when I click the link in navigation. Is there any other way that it does not cause this loop?
I updated codesandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Parent.js` :

1. Create a method called `onLinkChange(e)` which sets `this.state.data` to the `e`(url) and pass the method to `Navigation` as a `prop`.
2. Give `ListApp` a prop called `data` and set it to `this.state.data`.

In `Nav.js` when you click a link call `this.props.onLinkChange(url)`.

When you click on a link, it will call the `onLinkChange()` and set the new state of data which would be the URL resulting in the ListApp having access to the new URL through `this.props.data`

More in-depth explanation here: https://codeburst.io/no-redux-strategy-for-siblings-communication-3db543538959

Comment: Oh my mistake, ListApp is sibling, not parent. Nav.js and ListApp.js have same parent.

Comment: @mrKorny Updated answer.

Comment: Yes I used that method with callback, and its wors, but when I try fetch I got infinite loop.

Comment: @mrKorny the reason you are getting an infinite loop is because in your `componentDidUpdate()` inside of `ListApp.js` you are calling `this.setState()` which is then running `componentDidUpdate()` again.

Comment: Right, But if I do not use it setState{items: resp.results} then I will not send new data to my cards.

Comment: @mrKorny create a variable in ListApp.js called `edited` and set it to true just before you call `setState({items: resp.results{)` and at the beginning of `componentDidUpdate()` check if `edited` is equal to true, and if it is, set it to false and return out of the function. That will solve the looping problem.

Comment: @mrKorny can you mark my answer as the correct answer, since I did answer your original question? I need some rep so I can upvote peoples questions and answers :)